# IE 11 freezes input box (search) with angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code,

HTML:

```
  <input type="text"
       class="form-control dropdown-toggle input-box"
       placeholder="{{ctrl.placeHolder | translate}}"
       data-toggle="dropdown"
       data-ng-model="ctrl.searchText"
       data-ng-change="ctrl.globalSearch()"
       data-ng-class="{'white-background' : ctrl.whiteBackGround, 'grey-background' : !ctrl.whiteBackGround}">
```

JS:

```
      ctrl.globalSearch = function() {
            $timeout.cancel(_globalSearchConfig.searchCanceller);
            _globalSearchConfig.searchCanceller = $timeout(_startGlobalSearch, 750);
        }



      function _startGlobalSearch() {

            _globalSearchConfig.results = []; //Clearing previous search results
            _globalSearchConfig.noResultsToDisplay = false;

            angular.forEach(_filters, function (filter) {
                angular.forEach(filter.ddlItems, function (ddlItem) {
                    if (ddlItem[filter.propertyOfListItem].toUpperCase().indexOf(_globalSearchConfig.searchText.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
                        var result = {};

                        angular.copy(ddlItem, result);
                        _globalSearchConfig.results.push(new GlobalSearchResult(result, filter));
                    }
                });
            });

        }
```

When I search fro a text then the input box gets locked and no data comes in drop down and this is happening only in IE11. Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: How many items are there in list? and also share the markup for dropdown.

Comment: @AnkushJain there are 35462  items in the list.

Comment: I am getting the error: 'it is not running due to long running script'.

Comment: WTF...You are trying to do a client-side operation with this many items and expect that the browser will not freeze. Though chrome is fast enough to handle such operations, not all the browsers are. And ideally, this is not a good practice to perform heavy client operations, which actually leads to the same problem of freezing the browser that you are currently having.

Comment: Agree with Ankush Jain, it is a heavy client operation (to use the nested foreach statement to loop through the 35462 options), you might try to create a list to store the dropdown options (so that we could only using one foreach statement to filter the data). Otherwise, you could also try to store the dropdown options at the server side, and using Ajax function to call it and get the filter data, then populated the DropDownlist.